# CSV to SQL DB automatic job

Tags: java, c#, sql, powershell, csv

I have several CSV files that have 65,000 rows each.
I have a file per month (Meaning the number of files increase with each month by +1),
And each day the last file is updated with another 50 rows.

I know the IMPORT option in SQL to import XSLX files and I want to use it in an automated job to be scheduled twice a day and import CSV files.

How can I do that?
I am willing to use Powershell\C#\Java\Batch languages to do this.

Thanks in advanced
(I did search the other threads but could not find any working solution).

Comment: Have you tried adding your import logic to a SQL Server Agent Job?  SQL server can list files within a directory, you can store that into a table, loop over the rows and delete/move the files when you're complete.

Comment: What is the import logic? I am using the wizard

Comment: is this SQL Server? if it is you need to look at SSIS, as thats ideal for this type of work.

Comment: CREATE TABLE #Contents
(
 ColumnA INT,
 ColumnB VARCHAR(50)
);

BULK INSERT #Contents
FROM 'C:\Something.csv'
WITH
(
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you are looking for, but cloveretl is a nice tool for import / data transformation. (If you do not want to do it from scratch)

http://www.cloveretl.com/download/community-edition

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CloverETL

and I am pretty sure you can run tasks from commandline.
May other data transformation libraries like spring integration could also be an option.